# Postsharp using generic interfaces

Tags: postsharp

Not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to access my generic interface when using LocationInterceptionAspect without using reflection?

I want to cast the current instance of an interface type (which is generic) and execute methods.

I am trying to accomplish the following, note the ICachable (which is invalid):

```
    public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var value = args.GetCurrentValue() as ICachable<T>;

        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Object type: {0} must be of type ICachable", value.GetType()));
        }

        value.Load();
        value.SetCache("COLC");

        args.ProceedGetValue();
    }
```

Comment: Probably not until/unless C# permits generic attributes, in which case you could pass 'T' through when decorating with the aspect. Shame, I could have used this quite alot also!

Comment: Have you tried expressions + delegate creation?